# How to update with an id code?

Tags: c#, mysql

My code is working like this: when I create a file in a folder, the database will get information about the file.|

```
query = "INSERT INTO files (name,size,last_edit,extension) VALUES('" + name + "','" +  
size + "',now(),'" + extension + "')";
```

This is the example.
When i change the file, the database will UPDATE the information about the file.
When i delete the file, the database will DELETE the information about the file

My question is: Now when i rename it in the folder, how do i rename it in the database? cause i can't think about anything to use at the "Where ...="
Size wont work, Name wont work(since the name is changed), last_edit wont work(since it changes all the time), extension wont work(since there could be multiple files with the same extension. So i created a primary key(ID)

This is how i created my table:

```
create table files (ID int not null auto_increment,name varchar(50),size
int,last_edit datetime,extension varchar(5), primary key (id));
```

I thought that i could do something with ID. But I don't have a clue how to make sure he chooses the right ID.

```
    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("File renamed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        name = e.Name;
        extension = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath);
        size = e.Name.Length;
        query = "update files set name='"+name+"' where ID=";
        query();
    }
```

My event Renamed.

Comment: Well you should be holding old name before renaming, so use old name to look-up desired data and update it.

Comment: @PLB I rename manually in the folder. so i can't keep the old name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood question you need to update database when file is renamed. To get notified when file is modified you can use [`System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.aspx) class.

For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Creating test file. Can be removed.
    File.WriteAllText("test.txt", "test");
    // object that will watch changes for your file on file system
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); //get current path.
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
    watcher.Renamed += watcher_Renamed;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private static void watcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    // This event is fired when file is renamed. Do your own stuff here.
    Console.WriteLine(e.OldName + " => " + e.Name);
}
```

**Edit:**

```
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("File renamed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
    name = e.Name;
    extension = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath);
    size = e.Name.Length;
    query = "update files set name='"+name+"' where `name`='" + e.OldName + "'";
    query();
}
```

Comment: @DanielDekok Then you'll be notified with both the new and old name of the file that is renamed. As long as you're not renaming too many files at once, and the service is always running when renaming, you'll get notified for each file.

Comment: @DanielDekok You need to specify path you want to watch and apply watch filter as well. Omitted in example.

Comment: @PLB I have specified the path and applied the watch filter.

Comment: @DanielDekok Just missed to enable raising events. :)

Comment: @DanielDekok Good. Now you have everything that is needed to update database. I am glad that solved your problem. If you think this solved your problem you should mark answer as accepted (tick on the left side of answer). ;)

Comment: @PLB I already got the code i was showing you, before i asked the question. It doesn't solve anything

Comment: @DanielDekok It's getting chat here that are not comments meant to be. You have old name that should work as a reference to look desired note in database and you have current name that should be written. If there's anything else update your question.

Comment: @DanielDekok You're welcome. BTW, take a look at _prepared statements_.

Comment: @DanielDekok This works, however you should be aware that if you ever rename a file while the service is not running, the database will never get back in sync again without manual updates, so it's a bit of a fragile solution.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Nice note. I guess OP should be implementing some kind of service.